# DWF coloured but SVF Black

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are using the model derivative to create the 3d model viewables, and sometimes we get this bug where the DWF is coloured but the output SVF is totally black.

Here's an example: https://yeni.cemer.com.tr/tr/deltoik-tirmanma-serisi---ca-1600-detay-2114
Click 360 to see the forge model. ( the website is not released so there is no SSL certificate, don't worry about the warning )

What seems to be the problems here? These are 3d models created from AutoCAD, exported to DWF. We are also using Inventor models but they seem to be working perfectly.

Comment: Can you please try the DWF and original DWG via viewer.autodesk.com? Are you using custom materials, and if so, are you submitting them with the DWF for translation?

Comment: https://viewer.autodesk.com/id/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YTM2MHZpZXdlci90MTYxMjk1MTkzNzY0Nl83MWExODIxMy0yOGM5LTRmYzgtODA5Zi01NTNlYjkxY2I5YjlfMTYxMjk1MTkzODE0Ny5kd2Y?sheetId=NDY5N2Q3NmItMzdkYS02MmE1LTI4MzgtNDJkYTg4ZGU1YTZi Same output @AugustoGoncalves

Comment: what about materials? did you manage to upload the DWG?

Comment: This is a DWF and Design Review shows the colours when I open it on that

Comment: ok, thanks for confirming. I see a few JS errors on your page, like trying to load extensions before the Viewer is ready, I would suggest trying it with a super basic page & JS code. https://yeni.cemer.com.tr/Viewer.aspx?UrunID=2114

Comment: Yeah but @AugustoGoncalves viewer.autodesk.com creates the same output, as well as the oss-manager page's viewer. Clearly there is something wrong with the MD

Comment: can you please share the model here or via forge.help[at]autodesk.com? please do not send any confidential information

Comment: I've just sent the files @AugustoGoncalves

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves we have another similar problem again.
Guys we have these small problems on the viewer, and we kinda need help i think,
https://viewer.autodesk.com/id/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YTM2MHZpZXdlci90NjM[…]9u?sheetId=NGNkM2I5MWUtNmYwNy00NDNmLWJjYTgtZGVkNDg3Yzc0N2Uy
https://cemer.com.tr/tr/witch-serisi---ggws-1009-p-special-detay-2367
The actual inventor file NOR the dwf doesn't have these small artifacts
BOTH have problems
we use Appearences inside inventor, aswell as material